# A word to represent a sound type, e.g. mono or stereo?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What could be a word (or two) that I could use generically to refer to a sound being mono or stereo?

I am looking to name a column that can contain either "mono" or "stereo" as the entry, but am struggling to come up with anything other than "sound type" which to me doesn't sound obvious what it contains.

I am sure there must be a more elegant word(s) that would be suitable - any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for software constructs is specifically off topic according to our [help].

Answer (score 0):

I would use **Track type**. It is used also in sound editing software like Audacity. It is not one word, but IMHO is the best fit.

But as a technician who works sometimes with audio, I would add that it depends on your needs and target audience:

**Will your recording be always only mono or stereo?**

- If yes, them "Track type" should be ok. Even "mono/stereo" might not be bad for less technical people.
- If not, then I would probably go for "number of channels" and specify them by number.

Comment: In a recording context "track type" could also mean audio or MIDI.

Answer (score -1):

If only *stereo* and *mono* are available, **width** is probably the most straight-forward.

If at least one *surround* option is also available, **layout** may be best.

If you want to be over-the-top, **soundscape** speaks.

Comment: @DjinTonic -- Thanks for the information. Might one still use *width* in a figurative sense? How about the term *aurality* from my original comment on the question? One issue here is having something intuitive and elegant to users, as opposed to strictly correct at any expense. Still, I welcome to see reasonable alternatives.

Comment: Although all of these could **arguably** stand for being-mono-or-stereo, none of them will be so understood outside a context that makes it clear that this is what is meant. If what is wanted is something that will be readily understood without explanation, nothing is better than ***mono or stereo?***.

Comment: @jsw29 -- One question in that regard is whether the options *stereo* and *mono* are immediately visible or whether the panel or column must be opened or expanded, or whether an empty dropdown is used versus radio buttons (or similar).

Comment: I see @Michael commented on a comment that I deleted. Wiki defines [apparent source width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_source_width) as "the audible impression of a spatially extended sound source." As I understand it, this is one of the parameters in the "sound stage" one creates mentally when listening to a recording and can vary greatly with even two channels depending on how the recording is engineered. I would not use "width" as a label for the number of channels.

Comment: @DjinTonic -- What is your opinion on *channel mode* or simply *mode*? I suppose *L/R mode* is another.

Comment: @Michael I'm deeply interested in playing and listening to music, but I'm no expert on sound technology. I suggest looking at published tables that have similar parameters as headings. *Mode* may have an established meaning. There are lots of factors, such as music originally recorded digitally vs. digital remastered ones and the number of separate channels (as I understand it), e.g. Dolby 5.2.